# "More Like This" on CLucene

Tags: c++, search, lucene, information-retrieval, clucene

Currently Java Lucene has feature called “More Like This”, which is used to find representative terms of a document which can be further  searched to find similar documents.

I looked in latest CLucene code, but could not find this functionality.

Is it there in CLucene or something related to it? If not then are there any plans to include it?

If someone has done some work on this or area similar to this on CLucene, It will be great to hear from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess **CLucene** is just dead.

> Currently you can get CLucene in two flavors - one is the 0.9.21
>   release, which has been proven to be stable over time, but is only
>   compatible with Java Lucene 1.9.1. Another option is our current
>   working copy on git, which conforms with Java Lucene 2.3.2

And according to this quote from **sourceforge** - you will never get **MoreLikeThis** feature, cause port of **Lucene** 1.x or 2.x is just too old.

Code: http://sourceforge.net/p/clucene/code/ci/master/tree/ (look at the commit date)